# Redraw and clear a part of plot independent

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to change a plot slightly without redrawing the complete plot because of performance issues.

[image]

While mouse is moving on the upper plot, I want to draw dotted vertical line on all diagrams at cursor's x position. Because of performance I don't want to draw the entire plots again, but only the vertical line.

I was able to show lines by clicking with `axvline()`, but then I have the problem to delete the drawn line if the plot is clicked again.

I would like to have kind of second layer on each plot, I can draw and clear independent. Later I want additionally draw a dot on intersection of plot and vertical line and print the y-value under it.

I found [this](http://bastibe.de/2013-05-30-speeding-up-matplotlib.html) about drawing the parts of a plot independent like label and scale. But I want to redraw a part of the diagram. Is there anyway to get a additional layer or other way to draw efficiently?

The application is based on `PyQt4` with `matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg`.

**Minimal layout code for IPython notebook**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 2, wspace=0.1, height_ratios=[3,1,1])
main_plot = plt.subplot(gs[0, :])
sub_plots = [plt.subplot(gs[1, x]) for x in range(2)]
sub_plots.extend([plt.subplot(gs[2, x]) for x in range(2)])

main_plot.plot(np.arange(100), [np.random.randint(0, 100) for y in range(100)])
for sub_plot in sub_plots:
    sub_plot.plot(np.arange(100), [np.random.randint(0, 100) for y in range(100)])
```

**reduced code in my application**

```
def __init__(self):
    self.figure = Figure((20.0, 10.0), dpi=100)
    self.figure.patch.set_color('w')

    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 2, wspace = 0.1, height_ratios=[3, 1, 1])
    self.main_plot = self.figure.add_subplot(gs[0, :])
    self.sub_plots = [self.figure.add_subplot(gs[1, x]) for x in range(2)]
    self.sub_plots.extend([self.figure.add_subplot(gs[2, x]) for x in range(2)])

    self.plotCanvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
    self.plotCanvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self._on_click)

def _on_click(self, event):
    if event.inaxes == self.main_plot:
        self.main_plot.axvline(event.xdata)
        for plot_area in self.sub_plots:
            plot_area.axvline(event.xdata)

        self.plotCanvas.draw()
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `set_xdata`? Try to add a reference to the axvline-object in the `__init__`, i.e. `self.vline = ax.axvline(some_x)` (if you want to hide the vline before it is used you can put it outside of the xlims). Now inside the `_on_click` you call `self.vline.set_xdata(event.xdata)` instead of making a new axvline. Since the artist is already present in the plot mpl should only redraw `self.vline`.

Try the following example to see how it works:

```
import matplotlib as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
fig.show() #note that show will only "work" if you use ipython. use plt.show() otherwise.
vl = ax.axvline(0.3)
fig.canvas.draw()
vl.set_xdata(0.6)
fig.canvas.draw()
# plt.show()
```

When drawing your circle for the interception you can use the same trick, i.e. making a reference to it in the `__init__` and then use `self.circle.set_data(new_x, new_y)`.

Comment: If I do not plot any data, I see a line changing it's position. That is nice. But performance is still very low and if I plot data, the line is hidden by the plot. I tried to tweak with 'zorder', but it does not change anything.